# Android Programming - wifi direct video streaming

Tags: video, video-streaming, wifi-direct

I have a video cam which can be transmit video signal through a 2.4Hz wifi transmitter. The receiver can receive the signal and display the video on TV with video input.

Is it possible to write an APP to simulate the receiver? (i.e. display the video on the tablet or phone through wifi-direct)

Answer (score 0):

Simply being on 2.4GHz doesn't make it WiFi. For it to be feasible it must be in accordance with IEEE 802.11 so it can negotiate connections and authentications. 
If this is the case, then it's possible. But it's probably a lot easier to start developing on normal workstation before moving on to mobile apps.